# Change the background color with a javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to write a JavaScript code that will change the background color of all the buttons I click on (class is nav-bckStyle) when I click on button, and return to the original background color (class is nav-bck) when I click on them again. However, when I create a function with forEach(), when I click on img, it only changes the background color of img, but not the color of the buttons. Similarly, when I click on text, it only changes the background color of text. How should I code this?

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
        <nav>
            <div class="navGroup nav-bck">
                <button class="category-button" data-group="groupA">
                    <img src="/3th/img/rice-kimchi.png" alt="rice and kimchi">
                    <h4>lorem</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navGroup nav-bck">
                <button class="category-button" data-group="groupB">
                    <img src="/3th/img/fruit-vegetable.png" alt="fruit and vegetable">
                    <h4>lorem</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navGroup nav-bck">
                <button class="category-button" data-group="groupC">
                    <img src="/3th/img/meat-seafood.png" alt="meat and seafood">
                    <h4>lorem</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navGroup nav-bck">
                <button class="category-button" data-group="groupD">
                    <img src="/3th/img/frozenFood-snack.png" alt="frozen-food and snack">
                    <h4>lorem</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navGroup nav-bck">
                <button class="category-button" data-group="groupE">
                    <img src="/3th/img/etc.png" alt="etc">
                    <h4>lorem</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.nav-bck{
  background: rgb(1, 167, 1);
}
.nav-bckStyle{
  background: rgb(1, 107, 1);
}
#nav nav .navGroup {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#nav nav .navGroup img {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 60px;
}
#nav nav .navGroup h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#nav nav button {
  background: transparent; 
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

JS

```
categoryButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const navGroup = this.documentElement.querySelectorAll('.navGroup');
            console.log(navGroup);
    
            function navStyle(event){
                // navGroup의 class인 nav-bck 제거
                navGroup.forEach((e) => {
                    e.classList.remove('nav-bck');
                });
    
                // click한 navGroup에 nav-bckStyle class 추가
                event.target.classList.add('nav-bckStyle');
            }
    
            // 클릭 시 실행
            navGroup.forEach((e) => {
                e.addEventListener('click', navStyle);
            });
        })
    })
```

Comment: "However, when I create a function with forEach(), when I click on img, it only changes the background color of img, but not the color of the buttons" — We can't tell why your code isn't working if you don't show it to us. Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: I'm so sorry. I've added the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the `nav-bck` class from elements matched by `.navGroup` but you're adding it to elements you click on (such as images or level 4 headings).

You should add the class to elements matched by `.navGroup` instead. Search up the DOM from the `target` using [the `closest` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).